# Calling a rest client from a net beans project

Tags: java, rest, user-interface

I am new to Java GUI, I have knowledge of core Java.
I have to call a REST client from my NetBeans project, give values to it, and receive its output in the same project.

Please point me to some helpful resources.

Comment: Please add what you have tried to find so far, and where it has fallen short so we can help.

Comment: Sir, I browsed through tutorials of gui I understood how to receive a input ang give outputs but involving rest client to give input was something I was unable to find.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial covers the basics using Twitter's REST api which should be stable enough for you to be confident that any errors you see are in your implementation and not the API.

"In this tutorial, you create a NetBeans platform application that consumes the Twitter What Are You Doing service, displaying a list of your Twitter friends' status messages. First you create the platform application. You select the libraries needed in the application. Then you create a NetBeans module. Finally, you add a RESTful client and some basic display elements to the module. The client uses OAuth authorization."

https://netbeans.org/kb/72/websvc/jersey-rcp-client.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at the Oracle documentation on JAX-RS clients, which is how you can access REST resources using Java.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs-client.htm

In addition, client libraries like RestEasy and Jersey can help make your life even easier.

When dealing with RESTful webservices, you'll also want to know how the request bodies map to your Java objects. Are you using XML, JSON, a combination? It will help to know that as well so that you know if you need an XML mapping framework or a JSON mapping framework. You can just parse the strings, but depending on how complex it is, that might get really messy!